# Decorator returns function object instead of output of wrapped function

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Apologies, I can only imagine that StackOverflow is full of people who are almost there, but still don't quite grasp decorators.

I am trying to decorate a series of os-related functions so that if there are any exceptions such as FileNotFoundError or PermissionError, the user can fix the problem on their side and try again.

So I've created this toy function and decorator, and I don't understand where I'm not following properly the example decorators I've been reading, and I'm having trouble reasoning my way through it:

```
from functools import wraps

def continual_retry(func):
    def retry_decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        @wraps(func)
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            while not stop:
                try:
                    func(*args)
                    stop = True
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Could not perform function {func.__name__}')
                    print(f' with args {repr(args)}')
                    print(f' due to error {e.class__}')    
                    redo = input('Retry (y/n)? ')      
                    if redo.lower() != 'y':
                        print('Exiting program due to error and user input')
                        sys.exit(0)
        return func_wrapper
    return retry_decorated

@continual_retry
def divide(a, b):
    return a/b
```

When I run the function `divide`, this is the result:

```
>>> divide(1, 2)
<function __main__.divide(a, b)>
```

Where I was expecting a result of

```
0.5
```

(Then I was going to test `divide(1, 0)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your decorator is a decorator *factory* that returns another decorator. You don't need a factory here, remove one layer:

```
def continual_retry(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Could not perform function {func.__name__}')
                print(f' with args {repr(args)}')
                print(f' due to error {e.class__}')    
                redo = input('Retry (y/n)? ')      
                if redo.lower() != 'y':
                    print('Exiting program due to error and user input')
                    sys.exit(0)
    return func_wrapper
```

You also need to *return the function result*, and I changed the `while` loop to an endless one with `while True:`, as a successful `return` will exit the loop. I also updated the call to `func()` to pass along keyword arguments (`return func(*args, **kwargs)`).

When Python encounters `@continual_retry`, it passes in the function object to the `continual_retry()` callable to replace the function with the result, as if you expected `divide = continual_retry(divide)`, but in your version `continual_retry(divide)` returns the `retry_decorated()` function, which itself, when called, finally returns the `func_wrapper` object. You want `func_wrapper` to be used to be the replacement.

Your double-layer approach is great when you want to *configure* a decorator, where the outer decorator factory function accepts arguments other than the function. The goal is to then use that as `@continual_retry(config_arg1, config_arg2, ...)` so that Python first calls that function to get a return value, and the decoration then happens by calling that return value.

You could, for example, add an option to limit the number of retries:

```
def continual_retry(limit=None):
    def retry_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            retries = 0
            while True
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Could not perform function {func.__name__}')
                    print(f' with args {repr(args)}')
                    print(f' due to error {e.class__}')    
                    redo = input('Retry (y/n)? ')      
                    if redo.lower() != 'y':
                        print('Exiting program due to error and user input')
                        sys.exit(0)
                    retries += 1
                    if limit is not None and retries > limit:
                        # reached the limit, re-raise the exception
                        raise
        return func_wrapper
    return retry_decorator
```

Now you *must* use `@continual_retry()` or `@continual_retry(<integer>)` when decorating, e.g.:

```
@continual_retry(3)
def divide(a, b):
    return a / b
```

because it is `continual_retry()` that produces the decorator, and `continual_retry(3)(divide)` produces the wrapper that replaces the original function.

Comment: As usual, Martijn, you go above and beyond and deliver a wonderful explanation. That's the part of my mental model I was missing, the boilerplate code I was emulating was a decorator factory. Thank you for taking the time to make all this clear to me!